# How do I import a file I wrote and call a function from it?

Tags: python, function, import

I want to call a program from another file - in this case I want to build a few games, each one on a different file, and on another file (Arcade Center) give the option to choose a game and then run the chosen one (calling the 'play_game function')

I tried to write simply "import TicTacToe" since it's in the same directory but it didn't work. I looked on previous questions and YouTube videos and found what I wrote in the photo attached (photo #2) but didn't work either.

TL:DR 
How do I call a function from another file?

This is the photo of the TicTacToe game (also called module?) that I wrote and that I want to import from another file:

[image]

This is my (failed) attempt at importing that game (module?) from a different file in the same directory:

[image: image2]

Comment: Please post the code instead of screen shots. You should use double blackslashes, forward slashes or raw strings for windows paths (but I can't copy / paste your strings to test). So append `"C:\\User\\..."`.

Comment: And only append up to ArcadeCenter, not TickTacToe. You want the directory your script is in.

Comment: @AyyAppAnAjith - I'm not sure what you mean. You have to use the module name, not the file name (`import TicTacToe` is correct, `import TicTacToe.py` is not).

Comment: You should copy / paste code, not just screen shots. And you don't really need to post the real TicTacToe module, just a few line hack of the module for demonstration. Make it easy for us to grab your code and test it!

Comment: This is how it's written: 
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ArcadeCenter")
import TicTacToe

TicTacToe.play_game()

The function is not called , meaning the game does not start.  @tdelaney

Comment: Is an error raised? Try copying TicTacToe.py to make a backup, then replace it with a simple script that just does `def play_game(): print(__file__)`. Now you have a function that will tell you it ran and where it is on disk. In Lobby.py, after importing TicTacToe, add `print("TicTacToe.__file__")` to see if it got the right thing.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is too vague for debugging. Can you tell us exactly what happens? Is an error raised when trying to import? Do you call the function but it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @tdelaney Changed the TicTacToe file to def play_game():
    print ("Hello World") -  looks exactly the same as before, it doesn't print anything, but this again comes up: C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ArcadeCenter\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ArcadeCenter\GameLobby\TicTacToe.py

Comment: If I understand, importing and calling the function do not fail, its just that nothing is printed. That suggests that you are importing a different TicTacToe.py somewhere. In that case, after importing, `print(TicTacToe.__file__)` to see what you get. Also, try running from the command line instead of in your GUI. And also, in your GUI you have "Run", "Terminal" and "Python Console" tabs. Have you checked all of them for output?

Comment: Is this what you mean? this is from the terminal window: (venv) C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\ArcadeCenter>TicTacToe.play_game()
'TicTacToe.play_game' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I looked at all other tabs - nothing. Thanks for helping me i'm sure we are close to figure this out @tdelaney

Comment: Hey Tdelaney, any new ideas maybe? It still doesn't work.. :/ @tdelaney

Answer (score 0):

Put your files outside of the venv folder. Create a project and inside the parent directory create your python files, or simply create your files if you are working on standalone files. The venv folder is folder created by the virtual manager and hold and manages files which aren't yours. It would even work if 'lobby.py' is outside of the venv folder.

Also,use double backslashes, or forward slashes for windows paths

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I did it but it still doesn't work. Tried the double backslash/forward slashes, and the files were already outside the Venv directory so I put them in another sub directory to the project called "GameLobby"
Nothing's changed.. code: 

import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\ArcadeCenter\\GameLobby")
import TicTacToe

TicTacToe.play_game()

Comment: Use either C:\\Users\\user\PycharmProjects\ArcadeCenter\GameLobby" or, C://Users//user//PycharmProjects//ArcadeCenter//GameLobby. You don't need to use double forward slashes. Use double slashes or forward slash. To know why double forward slash is used before 'U%' string read about Unicode..